# Stop Fast Forwarding of AVPlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I am making an application in which I have implemented AVPLayer.I am getting the link from backend and showing the video in AVPlayer only,But I want to remove the functionality of moving forward and going back of video on the flag I am getting from backend.For some video It would work as normal and for some there would be restrictions.Also, I want to know the video completion time.How could I achieve it?

```
 @property (nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController* 
     videoPlayerViewController;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.delegate = self;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.player = self.videoPlayer;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    self.videoPlayer.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.allowsPictureInPicturePlayback = YES;
    self.videoPlayerViewController.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
    [self.videoPlayerViewController setValue:false forKey:@"requiresLinearPlayback"];
 CGRect videoFrame = self.videoPlayerView.bounds;
        [self.videoPlayerViewController.view setFrame:videoFrame];
        //[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
        [self addChildViewController:self.videoPlayerViewController];
        [self.videoPlayerView addSubview:self.videoPlayerViewController.view];
[self.videoPlayerThumbnailView setHidden:YES];
    [self.videoPlayer play];
```

Comment: you can use custom player look this lib https://github.com/piemonte/Player

Comment: are you not initialising your controller? `AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];`

Comment: NO, I am doing like thhis way.Do I need to initialise?

Comment: It's not working after initiisation also.

Answer (score 1):

Set `requiresLinearPlayback` to `false` to disable the playback.

```
self.playerController.setValue(false, forKey: "requiresLinearPlayback")
```

Here is the [doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1627633-requireslinearplayback).

Comment: How to use this n obj-c ?.It is throwing an error:Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'id _Nullable' is disallowed with ARC. My code is :  [self.videoPlayerViewController setValue:true forKey:@"requiresLinearPlayback"];

Comment: For objective-c `[self.playerController setValue:false forKey:@"requiresLinearPlayback"];`

Comment: Make sure your `videoPlayerViewController` is `AVPlayerViewController`

Comment: while writing your code , It is giving me crash saying: <AVPlayerViewController 0x1102b7c00> setNilValueForKey]: could not set nil as the value for the key requiresLinearPlayback.'.  I have used:[self.videoPlayerViewController setValue:false forKey:@"requiresLinearPlayback"];

Comment: please post your code in the question with initialisation of AVPlayerViewController

Comment: take into account that this was introduced in iOS 11, so if you try to use it on iOS 10 and lower it will crash